# Importing Virtual Images into AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We have an older application that is running on Windows server 2008 (the application is being refactored as we speak). Until that is done, I need to get a copy of Windows Server 2008 in AWS but it is not available through their one-click-through process. Therefore, I need to import an image or add an ISO and do an install that way (if that's even possible). I've gone though the AWS documentation on importing via the aws cli and to be frank, I don't get it and wasn't able to do the import. Other than AWS Command Line tools, is there another way to get a VM into AWS? I've considered loading an Ubuntu 18.04 and then installing VMPlayer (a VM within a VM) but even then, I'm not sure if the sub-vm would be accessible to the outside world (via security groups).

I've only been working with AWS for about a month so use small aws words. :)

Comment: It's just me working in the AWS account so for the import process, I don't think I need to worry about setting up an IAM account with roles and permissions. In reviewing the documentation with fresh eyes, I think I just need to get my VHD file copied to S3 and then from there I can do the import. In doing it this way, I would remove some of the hurdles I'm crashing into. Agree? Disagree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all VMDK files are created equally. I ended up converting my image to an OVA file type and did not have any issues importing the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the ISO file create either a VMware or VirtualBox image. From there, you may convert this image into an EC2 AMI image and go from there.

Follow the steps to import Virtualbox instance https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/

Also first check if you can get a normal windows server instance from amazon and customize.

Keep in mind to use the same architecture 32 or 64 bit all across.

Comment: Windows server 2008 r2 is not listed. That's the same URL I was following when I ran into an issue following the command line instructions. Ideally I'd like to see a current YouTube video of how to do this.  I've searched but found nothing showing for the beginner; they all make too many assumptions about their audiences knowledge. /rant .

Comment: Ok  if you have the ova or vmdk file then follow the video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kbdMHZPZVEY

Comment: I've seen that video, too. Considering it's only 4 months old, I ran into a problem within the first 2 minutes. I may watch it again tomorrow with fresh eyes. Coffee can only do so much. :)

Comment: [VM Import/Export Requirements - VM Import/Export](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html#vmimport-operating-systems) lists **Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 (Standard, Web Server, Datacenter, Enterprise) (64-bit only)** as supported. Is your system 64-bit?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes, the system is 64 bit (Standard).